# Line by line comparison of two files to identify differences in some indices, in Python

Tags: python, biopython

I have two text files (a.txt and b.txt) as follows:

The a.txt file

```
ATOM      1  N   ALA A   1      -5.183   4.912  16.158  1.00  7.03           N
ATOM      2  CA  ALA A   1      -4.909   5.261  14.785  1.00  7.27           C  
ATOM      3  XXX ALA A   1      -3.462   4.829  14.608  1.00  6.95           C
ATOM      4  O   ALA A   1      -2.679   4.968  15.551  1.00  8.51           O
```

The b.txt file

```
ATOM      1  N   ALA A   1      -5.183   4.912  16.158  1.00  7.03           N
ATOM      2  CA  ALA A   1      -4.909   5.261  14.785  1.00  7.27           C  
ATOM      3  YYY ALA A   1      -3.462   4.829  14.608  1.00  6.95           C
ATOM      4  O   ALA A   1      -2.679   4.968  15.551  1.00  8.51           O
```

I need a python code that:

1. Opens the two files
2. Reads the first line of the first file
3. Reads the first line of the second file
4. Compares the characters in the 13:16 indexes of the lines (N  )
5. If they match, go to the second line of the files
6. If the characters in the 13:16 indexes of the first lines do not match, print “atoms do not match” and exit the program.
7. If all the characters in the 13:16 indexes of all the lines match, print "All atoms are matched."

The program must be stopped in the third line because the characters in indexes 13:16 are different (XXX vs. YYY).
It does not work properly when I use the following code. Would you be able to suggest any openings?

```
file_1 = "a.txt"
text_1 = open(file_1, "r")
data_1 = text_1.read()
with open(file_1, 'rt') as myfile_1:
    file_2 = "b.txt"
    text_2 = open(file_2, "r")
    data_2 = text_2.read()
    with open(file_2, 'rt') as myfile_2:
        for line_a in data_1.split("\n"):
            a = line_a[13:16]
            for line_b in data_2.split("\n"):
                b = line_b[13:16]
                if a != b:
                    print("atoms do not match")
                    break
                else:
                    print("All atoms are matched.")
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues in your code.

First, you don't need to read the full contents of your files. This may be irrelevant if the files are small, but it is definitely a waste of both time and memory space: why read 1 thousand lines just to discover the third lines don't match, as in your example?

Second and most important, you are comparing *each* line from a to *each* line from b.

Third, also important, the `break` statement will only eit the innermost loop, so execution will continue anyway.

Fourth, why are you opening the files twice?

Try this

```
file_1 = "a.txt"
file_2 = "b.txt"
with open(file_1, 'rt') as myfile_1:
    with open(file_2, 'rt') as myfile_2:
        for line_a in myfile_1:
            a = line_a[13:16]
            line_b = myfile_2.readline()
            b = line_b[13:16]
            if a != b:
                print("atoms do not match")
                break
        else:
            print("All atoms are matched.")
```

Answer (score 0):

You opened files with two different ways by using `open` and `with open`. Just use one of them to read your file. Let's use just `open`. So your code will be:

```
file_1 = "a.txt"
text_1 = open(file_1, "r")
data_1 = text_1.read()
file_2 = "b.txt"
text_2 = open(file_2, "r")
data_2 = text_2.read()
for line_a in data_1.split("\n"):
    a = line_a[13:16]
    for line_b in data_2.split("\n"):
        b = line_b[13:16]
        if a != b:
            print("atoms do not match")
            break
        else:
            print("All atoms are matched.")
```

Now your code opens files just onces. However, you need to also close those files when your job is done if you use `open`. `with open`, automatically close files but `open` does not. To close files basically add `text_1.close()` and `text_2.close()`.

The other problem is, you want to make comparison with lines for the same indexes in two files. But your code compares them like that:

for line 1 in data 1 compare all lines in data 2. You need to fix it. We can use indexes.

```
for ind, line_a in enumerate(data_1.split("\n")):
    a = line_a[13:16]
    line_b = data_2.split("\n")[ind]
    b = line_b[13:16]
    if a != b:
        print("atoms do not match")
        break
    else:
        print("All atoms are matched.")
```

Now we made comparisons for the same indexes. Here just we need to change else statement. We want to print "All atoms are matched." after all comparisons. Thus else statement can be deleted. Instead we can add a boolean variable and change it if atoms do not match. It means that if all lines are matched our boolean variable will not be changed. Then, we can check it after files are read.

```
boolean = True
for ind, line_a in enumerate(data_1.split("\n")):
    a = line_a[13:16]
    line_b = data_2.split("\n")[ind]
    b = line_b[13:16]
    if a != b:
        print("atoms do not match")
        boolean = False
        break
if boolean == True:
    print("All atoms are matched.")
```

You can also close files before `if boolean == True:` because our job was done with the files. I hope helps.